# Browning and dying leaves on Lotus

Tags: diagnosis

Here is a picture of the brown leaves [image: Lotus in California]

Comment: The picture didn't link properly I guess, can you try again ?

Comment: And please use the built-in photo upload function - click [edit], then the image icon and flow the instructions in the pop-up.